# input stream versus getline in C++

Tags: c++

I have a character array `char input[11];`. I have a loop:

```
do {
  is >> input;      // is is an input stream defined by istream& is
} while (something)
// works fine

do {
  is.getline(input, 11);
} while (something)
/* i enter 10 digits and press enter, cursor still blinks,
i enter another value and finally it proceeds to the next piece of code */
```

What is the difference between the two, why does one read in all 11 characters (10 digits + enter) and the other is left hanging?

Comment: Use `string` and write `std::string input; do std::getline(is, input); while(something);`

Comment: You can read strings with spaces by using `getline()`

Comment: When you say "press enter" etc, do you mean that `is` is actually `cin` when you run the code?

Comment: Could you show the full code? The `getline` call should return when it encounters a newline.

Comment: I don't know about any difference. Both behave the same with respect to newlines and return the word or line read.

Comment: Try to specify an explicit delemiter. Also notice that n should be 12 instead of 11 (10 digits + newline + nullchar)